# How to manage multiple applications that share 90% of the code?

Tags: angular

We have multiple products but most of the code base is shared (>90%).
We are struggling to figure out how to manage the Angular frontend.

Differences are in many parts of the application and sometimes are very small (like change in the text for some component).
For now, we have one git branch for every product and one branch for the core but it doesn't seem like a perfect solution.

There is one more general question on this subject: [multi-product architecture, with large common part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565625/multi-product-architecture-with-large-common-part) but it is unanswered.

Can you propose any good practice that we should follow?

Comment: Load the text from a database, depending on user/product/whatever

Comment: Changing the text was just an example but most of the differences are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Angular client, you could use the

```
ng generate application <site1> 
ng generate application <site2> 
ng generate application <common>
```

You can then put all your common code/components/services etc... in the commmon site.

Then use the --project command line option to create your stuff

```
ng g services servies/user --project common
ng serve site1
ng serve site2
```

I quickly created a demo repo on github if you want to see.

[angular-multiple-projects-demo](https://github.com/duranmg/angular-multiple-projects-demo)

Answer (score 0):

There is no single good answer to this and will depend very heavily on your development situation and your business needs. Two thoughts:

1) I think you could build small packages of functionality and serve them via `npm`. That might be a lot of work.
2) Using `git` in the manner you've described seems less than ideal.